# Как в гугл таблицах реализовать отображение стрелки вверх или вниз со значением?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Нужно для понимания прогресса или регресса в соревнованиях, допустим раз в неделю проводится тест и хотелось бы видеть как по сравнению с прошлой неделей выступил участник +2 или -3. Но визуально удобнее со стрелками.

апд. Нашел как это сделать в Excel описание тут: https://exceltable.com/formatirovanie/kak-sdelat-strelki-v-yacheykah

Для гуглтаблиц тоже можно, но сложнее, чуть позже добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Пользовательский формат и смайлики [image: формат]
https://t.me/google_sheets/455